# Rename Buddy Group In Finch

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin, finch

I use Finch as my primary IM client.  I have divided my buddies up into groups, but I made an error when I was naming the groups.  How can I rename a buddy group from within Finch?  Is it even possible?

Unfortunately, the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/finch/) and the [FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch) are silent on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just edit ~/.purple/blist.xml

Comment: I ended up figuring that out later and forgot to come back to this question.  Thanks.  It's not "within" Finch, but at least it's possible.